# Calling Stripe API but getting no action

Tags: javascript, vue.js, stripe-payments

I am having an issue with `stripe.customers.create`. My intent is to create a Stripe customer with currentUser's email address, then update my user with the returned `customer.id`.

`stripe.customers.create` returns a promise but nothing is firing within the `then` or `catch` statements. The Stripe customer is not being created and it looks as though the Stripe API call isn't even going out to Stripe.

```
stripe.customers.create({
  email: state.getters.currentUser.email
})
.then(customer => {
  console.log("promise resolved");
  console.log(`customer.id: ${customer.id}`);
  if (customer.email === state.getters.currentUser.email) {
    state.dispatch("updateUserProperty", {
      customerId: customer.id
    });
  }
})
.catch(err => {
  console.log("promise error");
  console.error(err);
});
```

I have also tried this syntax without luck:

```
async () => {
  const params: Stripe.CustomerCreateParams = {
    email: state.getters.currentUser.email
  };
  const customer: Stripe.Customer = await stripe.customers.create(params);
  console.log(customer.id);
};
```

I am using https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node and no errors or warnings are throwing. `state.getters.currentUser.email` indeed has the desired value.

What am I missing here? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you initializing the library with your secret key? `const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_...');` See: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#usage

Comment: Ah, yes, as Cosimo mentioned below it looks like you're trying to use `stripe-node` in the front end. It is meant for server-side usage only. You should use StripeJS for collecting payment details in the front end, and actions like Customer creation should be managed with API calls to your server.
https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js

Comment: Can you please expand on "actions like Customer creation should be managed with API calls to your server"?  I'm not sure what path to go down at this point.

Comment: Take a look at a basic example guide ( https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment#web ) or sample app ( https://github.com/stripe-samples/accept-a-card-payment/tree/master/using-webhooks ). You'll see that there is both a client and server aspect. You need to operate a back-end server to make some of the Stripe calls with your secret key. You can't do that safely in the client/browser. Your front-end app needs to make calls to your server to handle some of the work.

Answer (score 0):

that library must be used in node environment, vue or client side cannot use this library